# Letsencrypt renewal getting - remote error: tls: handshake failure

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to renew my letsencrypt certs and getting the following error:

remote error: tls: handshake failure

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

I had Cloudflare running on the site, once I paused it I could renew the certs.

Answer (score 1):

Consider specifying the `http-01` method. For example,

```
sudo certbot renew --preferred-challenges http-01
```

The `http-01` challenge works by generating a file at a specific web-accessible location under the domain under consideration. The challenge relies on HTTP (port 80) rather than HTTPS (e.g., the `tls-sni-01` challenge method). Avoiding reliance on TLS can be a step forward in addressing the error you encounter.

The `--preferred-challenges`, perhaps self-evidently, cues certbot, for plugins which can handle more than one challenge method.

Comment: In light of the answer posted by the OP and in general you may want to explain what that option does and why that work-around  may solve the problem. For instance *“by renewing over plain http on port 80 rather than over https on port 443, you can avoid TLS warnings.”* BTW when you redirect http to https you will still get an error unless you exclude the /.well-known/acme-challenge path from such a redirect

Comment: @HBruijn Thanks for the cues for additional elaboration.